# How to install image library in python 3.6.4 in windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, image, pycharm

I am new to Python and I am using Python 3.6.4. I also use PyCharm editor to write all my code. Please let me know how can I install Image library in Windows 7 and would it work in PyCharm too.

Comment: As you are using pycharm, you need to select the env. In that env install the image package from settings

Comment: @kvmahesh can you please elaborate more on how to select env in PyCharm and how to find settings in env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `pycharm`,

1. goto `settings` -> `project Interpreter`
2. Click on `+` button on top right corner and you will get pop-up window of 
   `Available packages`. Then search for `pillow`, `PIL` image python packages.
3. Then click on `Install package` to install those packages.

Comment: @Ratnakar Mittal: Let me know if you need further information

Comment: @Ratnakar Mittal: Great !!. Please confirm the answer as you got the desired information

Comment: Mahesh, though i was able to install many other libraries but PIL, Image, PySide, Pillow-PIL they all fail due to "Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pil/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pil/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),)) - skipping" error. Can you tell me what to do next. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Try to install  the `pillow` module.

Comment: I have installed pillow module, it has just three functions in it main, not and par. There is no <image> function which i can use to process images. I also read that PIL is obsolete for Python 3.6. Is it not possible to process/work on images in 3.6.4 version?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs)(working win7 binaries) and install **Pillow**(since PLI is dead now!) or try [this](https://wp.stolaf.edu/it/installing-pil-pillow-cimage-on-windows-and-mac).